# Produce a list of the most-similar units, given various correlations/relationships

Tags: analysis, algorithms, recurrence-relations, relations, recursive-algorithms

I have a database full of units (U1 - U50, U51...) where every unit has the same standard attributes (A1 - A10) and where a % of each attribute defines the amount of that attribute for that particular unit.

**[Here is a Dropbox link to the Excel document, for reference.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2rwo9vljpbbq9of/ItemRelationMap.xlsx)**

*Defining a **Unit** by it's value of the standard **Attributes** looks something like this:*

[image]

-

With that, there is a relationship that each **Attribute** has with every other. Some attributes are similar to another attribute, while others are not.

*The **Attribute-to-Attribute** similarity matrix looks something like this:*

[image]

-

Lastly, a **User** has the ability to *rate* any random **Unit**, at which point it gets stored in a special list.

The User-Rated list looks something like this:

[image]

-

The goal is to produce a separate list of the units that are the **most similar** to each unit in the user-rated list, *while taking into account what rating the user has given to all the other units in their list*.

---

**Essentially**: Upon rating a new unit, what units from the unit-database would the user like the most (given their history of other unit ratings)?

The algorithms (and Excel formulas) needed for this are beyond my knowledge. I've set this up in Excel the best way I know how. There might be better ways of solving this by altering the data (i.e. making the Attribute-similarity matrix a collinear matrix). I just don't know. To anybody who can solve this, thank you. If you can perhaps share with me what proper mathematical areas are included in this sort of problem, that would be fantastic. If you can work out how to do this in Excel, that would be amazing.

**[Here is a Dropbox link to the Excel document.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2rwo9vljpbbq9of/ItemRelationMap.xlsx)**

Comment: Contact NetFlix.  They've had a lot of interest http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix_Prize in this sort of problem.

Comment: @EricTowers I read about this. Crazy. It only took three years for someone to come up with an answer that bested Netflix's algorithm. You know what? This has inspired me. Whoever can produce the best algorithm for this problem will win a grand prize of TWENTY-FIVE WHOLE DOLLARS in addition to your answer being marked as best. Please submit your answers to this page and good luck!